# Box counting dimension of a set and Lipschitz functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

If $f$ is Lipschitz, then the following holds for the Hausdorff dimension:
$$\dim_H f(A) \le \dim_H A.$$

Is the same true for the box counting dimension?

Comment: And what difference does this switch make in the proof you know? (I assume that the Lipschitz  constant is uniform)

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is still true, you simply map the covering using $f$. Let $L$ denote the Lipschitz constant for $f$.  For a given $\epsilon$, suppose that $A$ can be covered by $N_A(\epsilon)$ sets of diameter at most $\epsilon$, and $N_A(\epsilon)$ is minimal.  Then mapping each set in the cover using $f$ we get a cover of $f(A)$ 
that yields $N_{f(A)}(L \epsilon) \le N_A(\epsilon)$. The upper box counting dimension of $A$ is the limsup of  $(\log N_A(\epsilon))/(-\log \epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Now $$(\log N_{f(A)}(L \epsilon))/(-\log (L\epsilon)) \le   (\log N_A(\epsilon))/(-\log \epsilon) \cdot  (\log (L\epsilon))/   (\log \epsilon).$$ 
Taking limsup gives the statement for upper box counting dimension, the proof for lower dimension is similar.

Comment: Yuval, could you please clarify why $N_{f(A)}(L\epsilon) \le N_{A}(\epsilon)$? I'm having trouble to see this in the case where $0<L<1$.

Comment: If $A$ is covered by sets $\{S_j\}$ for $j \ge 1$ then $f(A)$ is covered by sets $\{f(S_j)\}$ for $j \ge 1$. Observe that diam$f(S) \le  L$diam$(S)$ for any set $S$ by the definition of diameter.